# Chrome extension, Javascript: getting URL from address bar

Tags: javascript, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that I am working on that has a "pop-up" putton on the bar,
I visit a site (for example google.com) the button is pressed, I run this code in popup.html:

```
window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);

function windowLoaded() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    localStorage['url_in_address_bar']=tab.url;
  });
}
```

but instead of saving the google address, it saves it's own address like this: `"chrome://extensions/"`.

How do I get it to save the last address instead of itself?

Comment: `chrome://extensions/` is the extension managing page. Do you have that opened?

Comment: Yep, that is open... but in a few tabs behind

Comment: Again, your script works fine for me... If you have the Developer Tools open, the popup won't reload. What about closing Dev Tools, open the popup and then check `localStorage`?

Comment: ok, now it is givin me: chrome-extension://kjggpdimdloblnddfbnodggchjpalihb/1_options.html   
Thats still not the window that was previous :(

Comment: That must be the page that you had open at the time of clicking the popup. Are you sure you have Dev Tools closed, then go to some tab and click the popup. Then it is storing correctly for me.

Comment: Dev tools is closed, here is my exact code: http://pastebin.com/ugEsv6MF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows the problem. `getSelected` returns the tab as a callback, which means the callback is executed when Chrome has found the selected tab. This is **asynchronous**, and is executed later:

```
window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);

function windowLoaded() {
  // 1) request selected tab
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    localStorage['url_in_address_bar']=tab.url; // 3) selected tab is stored
  });
}


// 2) a tab is created
var saved_email = localStorage['blocker_user_email'];
if (saved_email === undefined ||  saved_email == "a@a.com")
{   
    //self.close();
    chrome.tabs.create({url: '0_register.html'});
} else{
      // self.close();
      chrome.tabs.create({url: '1_options.html'});
}
```

You could solve it by putting the second part of your code into the callback function:

```
window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);

function windowLoaded() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    localStorage['url_in_address_bar']=tab.url;

    var saved_email = localStorage['blocker_user_email'];
    if (saved_email === undefined ||  saved_email == "a@a.com")
    {   
        //self.close();
            chrome.tabs.create({url: '0_register.html'});
    } else{
          // self.close();
          chrome.tabs.create({url: '1_options.html'});
    }
  });
}
```

A callback function is a function you provide as an argument to another function (e.g. `getSelected`). When that other function has completed its task (e.g. find selected tab), it will execute the provided function. In the meantime, however, the code coming after the request will be executed regularly.

Comment: Can you show me how please? I am new to "callback functions" although i understand the async part